# Can we screen record Netflix strems?

Tags: drm

No I don't want to do it and I don't have a Netflix account but I have heard the different ways Netflix uses DRM to protect its content such as encrypted streaming and watermark. But someone can just use Screen recording software and put the movie into full screen and start screen recording with audio and I know the audio will be crappy but pirates will do anything to pirate content. So can't pirates just use screen recording software and record the screen. Or does Netflix prevent this?

Comment: a lot of windows API that are normally used to screen shot won't work on DRM viewports; they show up as black rectangles.